# NSSet use predicate to return objects matching given class

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, nsset

Let's say I have an NSSet that contains a collection of objects of type id<Shape>

. . .  of which there are CircleShape, SquareShape, HexagonalShape instances put into it (not the real protocol or class names) . .

is it possible to use a predicate or another single line of code to return all of the instances of CircleShape?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a block-based predicate like this:

```
NSSet *yourSet = ...;
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[CircleShape class]];
}];
NSSet *filteredSet = [yourSet filteredSetUsingPredicate:pred];
```

This would return all instances of `CircleShape` or subclasses of `CircleShape`. Use `isMemberOfClass` if you want only instances of the class, but not of subclasses.