# How i know the index of Array object in NSCountedSet

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code for getting duplicate Device Contacts and i want to know how to get the index of the duplicate contacts

```
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:[Contact valueForKey:@"emailAddress"]];

for(id name in set){
    if([name isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [name isEqualToString:@""]){

    } else {
        array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        duplicateEmailDictionary =[NSMutableDictionary new];
        if ([set countForObject:name]>1) {
            for (int i=0; i<[set countForObject:name]; i++) {
                [array addObject:name];
            }
            [duplicateEmailDictionary setObject:array forKey:@"emailAddress"];
            [finalDuplicateEmail addObject:duplicateEmailDictionary];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` on your array for each duplicate?

Comment: Hello Larme Can you send me some example code?

Answer (score 2):

A set is an unordered pool of unique objects. Since it's unordered, there is no integer index you can use to access specific elements of a set.

If you need index then use `NSArray`.

Comment: Then how i get the particular index Objects

Comment: You can get the object by comparison but you cannot get the index

Comment: i already got the objects by comparing than what about the others objects values ? How i get that like Phone No, Name etc

Comment: Then you have to use nsarray and add a predicate that will solve your problem

Comment: sorry you can just use predicate on a set so that you will get all the values which matches your comparison

Comment: ex you can find from the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276018/nsset-use-predicate-to-return-objects-matching-given-class)